# Installed pgadmin4-apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: permissions, apache2, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to install pgAdmin4 desktop mode, Facing this Issue. It show pgAdmin4 and pgadmin4-apache2 installed. but while opening the pgAdmin4 application it display an error on popup

```
Failed to launch the application server, server thread exiting.
```

Although the command for installing `pgAdmin4` and `pgadmin-apache2`

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

Show the following error.

```
pgadmin4 is already the newest version (4.8-3.pgdg18.04+1).
pgadmin4-apache2 is already the newest version (4.8-3.pgdg18.04+1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-data apache2-utils libprotobuf-c1 php7.2-cli php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up pgadmin4-apache2 (4.8-3.pgdg18.04+1) ...
WARNING: Failed to set ACL on the directory containing the configuration database: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/www/.pgadmin'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 413, in <module>
    setup_db()
  File "setup.py", line 345, in setup_db
    create_app_data_directory(config)
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 42, in create_app_data_directory
    os.chmod(config.SESSION_DB_PATH, 0o700)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/www/.pgadmin/sessions'
dpkg: error processing package pgadmin4-apache2 (--configure):
 installed pgadmin4-apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pgadmin4-apache2E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this below command to avoid permission error:

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/.pgadmin/sessions
```

If the directory is not exists, create it before set the permission:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/.pgadmin/sessions
```